# Let $f:RP^2 \to RP^2$ be the smooth map

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f:RP^2 \to RP^2$ be the smooth map defined by
$$
 f([x:y:z])=\left[\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2+z^2}:\frac{y}{x^2+y^2+z^2}: \frac{2z}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \right].
$$
Show that
$$df_{[0:1:0]}:T_{[0:1:0]} RP^2 \to T_{[0:1:0]} RP^2$$
is given by $df_{[0:1:0]}(v)=2v$.

I start to create the map $\phi:RP^2 \to R^2$, $\psi: RP^2 \to R^2,$ and $\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}: R^2\to R^2$

I try to ues the definition that say: $df_x=d\psi^{-1}\circ d(\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1})\circ d \phi.$
Also, I try to take chart of point $[0:1:0] as $(U,\phi).$ Also,

I have $$\phi([x:y:z])=(x/y,z/y)$$ and the tangent space $T_{[0:1:0]}RP^2=[\delta^{'}(0)]$
and $[\delta^{'}(0)]$ is the class of the curves $$\delta:(-\theta, \theta)\to U$$
could $\hat{f}=\phi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$ be defined as $\hat{f}(x,y)=(2x,2y)$? so the $d\hat{f}=2I_{2\times 2}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please show us what you've tried. It's very hard to know what you know and what you don't know if you do not show us your work.

Comment: I try to use the following definition: $$df_x: T_xX\to T_y Y$$ is define as $$df_x=(d\psi)^{-1}\circ d( \psi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1}) \circ d(\phi)  $$

Comment: And what specifically are $\phi$ and $\psi$ here?

Comment: $\phi:RP^2\to R^2,$ and $\psi :RP^2\to R^2$ and it defied as $[x,y,z]\to (x/y.z/y)$, and $[2x/(x^2+y^2+z^2),y/(x^2+y^2+z^2),2z/(x^2+y^2+z^2)]\to (2x/y, 2z/y)$

Comment: No, open subsets. Which open subsets and what maps specifically?

Answer (score 1):

You can observe that

$f([x,y,z])=[\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}(2x,y,2z)]=[2x,y, 2z]$

A chart of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ around $[0,1,0]$ will be $\psi_1: U_1\to \mathbb{R}^2$ where $U_1:=\{y\neq 0\}$ and $\psi_1([x,y,z])=(\frac{x}{y},\frac{z}{y})$.

You know that each chart around a point $p$ induces a base on the tangent space of the manifold in the point $p$. If you have a smooth function $f: M\to N$ between two manifolds $M,N$ and if $\phi$ is a chart of $M$ around a point $p$ and $\psi$ is a chart of $N$ around the point $f(p)$ then the matrix associated to the linear map $df_p$ (with respect the bases induced by that charts) will be 
$J(\psi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1})(\phi(p))$

In our case you have that

$\phi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1}(a,b)=\phi(f(a,1,b)))=\phi(2a,1,2b)$

$=(2a,2b)$

So

$J(\phi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1})(\phi([0,1,0]))=$

$ J(\phi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1})(0,0)=2I$

Then

$df_{[0,1,0]}=2Id_{T_{[0,1,0]}\mathbb{RP}^2}$

Comment: I find that $J(\phi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1})$ but I end that I have $3\times 3$ matrix, $2\times 3$ matrix , and $3\times 3$ matrix. However I can not multiply the matrixes to other to get the answer

Comment: You must calculate first $\phi\circ f\circ \phi{-1} :\R^2 \to \R^2$ and then you must consider the Jacobian matrix

Answer (score 1):

A way to show this is to remark that you can lift $f$ to a map $g:S^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $g(x,y,z)=(2x,y,2z)$. The tangent space $T_{(0,1,0)}S^2$ is generated by $u=(1,0,0)$ and $v=(0,1,0)$ and $dg_{(0,1,0)}(u)=2u, dg_{(0,1,0)}(v)=2v$.  This implies that $dg_{(0,1,0)}=2Id$. Let $x\in T_{[0,1,0]}RP^2$, there exists $y\in T_{(0,1,0)}S^2$ such that $dp_{(0,1,0)}(y)=x$ where $p$ is the restriction of the quotient map $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow RP^2$ to $S^2$. You have $df_{[0,1,0]}(x)=dp_{(0,1,0)}(dg_{(0,1,0)}(y)=2x$ since $f\circ p=p\circ g$.

Comment: Thank you very much